# SpriteKit - Return to a persistent scene in the same state it was left in.

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

The concept of being able to return to a previous scene from where you left off is briefly mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit.html

Other than that I can't find any more documentation on the subject. I know in other frameworks like Cocos2D you can pop scenes on a stack, and even have multiple scenes running at the same time.

How do I get this to work in SpriteKit.

I have a game with a swiping menu for character selection. Upon selecting a character the scene changes to another menu. I want users to be able to hit a back button and be presented with the previous scene, where the character they selected is in full view.

At the moment I have it presenting the previous scene as a new one. Which of cause creates it in a fresh state, with the first character in plain view, and not the character they selected.

This should be really simple, but for all my googling, I do not have a clue on how to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if anyone is still checking this, but I believe that I have another way to solve the problem.

I made a custom "PauseScene" and the user can set a return scene, meaning that when you are ready to go back, the PauseScene's view presents the return scene. Here's the code:

PauseScene.h

```
#import "MAScene.h"

@interface PauseScene : MAScene
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) SKScene * returnScene;

-(void)setReturnScene:(SKScene *)otherScene;


@end
```

PauseScene.m

```
#import "PauseScene.h"
#import "MASpriteButton.h"


@interface PauseScene ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MASpriteButton * resumeButton;
@end


@implementation PauseScene


-(void)setReturnScene:(SKScene *)otherScene
{
    _returnScene = otherScene;
}


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    [self createContent];
}

-(void)createContent
{

    __weak typeof(self) weakMe = self;

    MASpriteButton * resume = [[MASpriteButton alloc] initWithBackgroundImageNamed:@"cardback.png" andSelectedImageNamed:@"cardback.png" andCallbackBlock:^{

        NSLog(@"removing...");
        [weakMe.view presentScene:self.returnScene];
    }];

    resume.size = CGSizeMake(self.widthToHeightRatio * 20, self.heightToWidthRatio * 20);
    resume.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);


    self.resumeButton = resume;
    [self addChild:self.resumeButton];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}


@end
```

The way I used it was that when the user hits a pause button in the gameplay scene, I call these lines:

```
self.paused = YES;
PauseScene * pScene = [[PauseScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
[pScene setReturnScene:self];
[self.view presentScene:pScene];
```

Note that `self` in this little block is the gameplay scene.

By having the pause scene keep a weak pointer to the gameplay scene, it can keep a pointer to the return scene without dealloc-ing it when the pause scene is dealloc-ed.

PS The MAScene class is just a little extension of the SKScene class, I just added a couple things to it. If anyone wants that too just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the menu scene is also implemented in Sprite Kit, you could create a modal view controller, present it, and put the Sprit Kit scene over that modal view.

So, specifically, create a new UIViewController inheriting class `MenuViewController`, and a new SKScene inheriting class, `MenuScene`. The class 'MenuScene' `MenuScene` should be the Scene you're looking to present. Hook up `MenuScene` and `MenuViewController` like you would normally hook up an `SKScene` and its view controller. Make sure you have the original scene's view controller as a property of the original `SKScene`.

Wherever you want to present this menu, you can call from the original SKScene:

`MenuViewController *modalViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
[self.viewController presentModalViewController:modalViewController];`

There are simpler ways to just transition b/w `SKScene` instances, but if you want to keep the intial `SKScene` running in the background, this is what you would have to do, I believe.

Comment: Do you have any links to guides or know of a way that may help with getting a modal view controller working in SpriteKit?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmmm. I've never done this personally, but I'll edit my post to contain some code.

Comment: Also the problem with this method is how I would go about sending information from one SKScene to the next. Won't I need to set properties on the ViewController being pushed then retrieve them on the next SKView?

Or perhaps just use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Without more knowledge of your project, it's hard to say

Answer (score 0):

You just should keep strong pointer to the leaving scene before you call new

Here is example of realisation via singleton (actually usual singleton with scene pointer, no magic)

```
@interface Global : NSObject

+ (Global*)sharedInstance;

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKScene *mainScene;
@end
```

And .m file

```
@implementation Global

+ (instancetype) sharedInstance{
    static Global *_sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[Global alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

@end
```