# Pausing and resuming a SpriteKit game

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

When i click the pause button I'm getting directed to another view controller that should be the "pause Menu". When i click resume in the pause menu, I'm getting directed back to the game but instead of resuming the game, it restarts. Can someone help me ? Im a beginner so Pls give as much explanation as you can Thanks! 
This is in my gameViewController

```
    @IBAction func pauseGame(sender: AnyObject) {

    scene.view!.paused = true



}
```

This is in my "pauseMenu" viewcontroller

```
 @IBAction func resumeGame(sender: AnyObject) {
     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "pauseToGame" {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! GameViewController

                destinationController.scene.view!.paused = false

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to avoid using `prepareForSegue` with SpriteKit but if you really need it
[seems here is what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25050235/5401878)

Comment: i checked out your link but its in c-objective and I'm using swift but thanks

Answer (score 0):

By segueing to another View Controller you are in essence tearing down your scene. I assume you are probably doing all the setup for your scenes in `didMoveToView(view: SKView)`. If so, when you transition back to the first View Controller from your pause menu view controller, `didMoveToView` is called again and is recreating your scene.

Comment: So how should I do it